# How to use this library in Kotlin?

Tags: android

```
colorPicker.setColorSelectionListener(new SimpleColorSelectionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onColorSelected(int color) {
    // Do whatever you want with the color
    imageView.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
  }
});
```

I am trying to use this color picker library which is in Java. I am not able to convert the code into Kotlin. How can I do so?

Comment: Here's the library "compile 'com.github.madrapps:pikolo:1.1.6'"

Comment: If you use IntelliJ, it's pretty good about converting java code into Kotlin for you automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will probably look something like

```
colorPicker.seColorSelectionListener(object : SimpleColorSelectionListener() {

  override fun onColorSelected(color:Int) {
     imageView.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
  }

});
```

Comment: It Worked !! Thank You So much :)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply copy paste the code and Android studio will convert. For convenience you can use it like.

```
colorPicker.setColorSelectionListener(object : SimpleColorSelectionListener() {
        override fun onColorSelected(color: Int) {
       // Do whatever you want with the color

        }
    })
```